# fail2ban apachefakegooglebot failregex location

Tags: ubuntu, fail2ban

Where do I put the failregex filter in fail2ban?
Do I put it in the jail.local or somewhere else?
I am running ubuntu 18.04

```
    [apache-fakegooglebot]
enabled=true
filter=apache-fakegooglebot
port=http,https
logpath=%(apache_access_log)s
maxretry=1
banTime=360000
failregex=<whatever>
ignorecommand=%(ignorecommands_dir)s/apache-fakegooglebot <ip>
action_=%(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s,bantime="%(bantime)s",port="%(port)s",protocol="%(protocol)s",chain="%(chain)s"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create apache-fakegooglebot.conf file in /etc/fail2ban/filter.d

```
# go to filter.d directory
cd /etc/fail2ban/filter.d

# create filter
sudo nano apache-fakegooglebot.conf

# add fail & ignore regex into the filter
failregex=<whatever>
ignoreregex=<whatever>
```

Comment: its in there i found a different problem

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/bin/fail2ban-client and fail2ban-server
```

and

```
/usr/bin/share/fail2ban-client and fail2ban-server
```

were calling for different versions of python I changed the header from

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```